# "This app is incompatible with all of your devices" for all Google Play users

Tags: android-studio, google-play

I have uploaded my app about two weeks ago to Google Play. It has zero installs, presumably because it says "This app is incompatible with all of your devices" to users. At least, that's what it says to me, including for the phones on which I actually developed the app (?!). It effectively greys out all my phones. No installation possible. What could be the problem? This is what the manifest looks like;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true">
</supports-screens>

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:label="FrontDoor"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

       <activity
           android:name=".Main"
           android:label="Input Page">

       </activity>

       <activity
           android:name=".Stats"
           android:label="Match Report Page" />

       <activity
           android:name=".Settings"
           android:label="Settings Page" />

       <activity
               android:name=".Help"
               android:label="Help Page" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Start"
        android:label="Front Door">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity
            android:name=".Eula"
            android:label="Eula Page" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Update"
        android:label="Update Page" />

    <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

</application>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```

Comment: check min sdk version setting in build.gradle

Comment: android.hardware.type.watch - really for watch?